# metodo heredado como pasar valores de un hashmap de la clase hija java

Tags: java, poo, herencia, patrones-de-diseño

Tengo esta pregunta, estoy trabajando en un proyecto y realmente trato de hacer los proyectos implementando todo lo que veo, se que podría hacerlo con `api`, pero por el momento no se como implementarlas y es algo que quiero estudiarlo bien para después componer mejor mi proyecto.
Siguiendo con el tema, me di cuenta que un método donde convierto las monedas es un código que se repite en las diferentes clases, ya que cree una clase para convertir a **Dolar**, otra para convertir a **pesos mexicanos** etc etc.
Leí sobre un patrón de diseño y traté de implementarlo pude hacer el proyecto, pero solo es esa cuestión, el método se repite en todas las clases, quise hacer una clase donde pudiera heredar solamente los atributos y el método, pero ese método contiene un `JoptionPane` para preguntar que conversión quiere, si de `pesos mexicanos` a `dolares` etc etc. hice en cada clase un `hashmap` para poner el nombre de la moneda y el precio, cuando heredo el método me sale el método creado con el `super` pero no puedo pasarle el valor del `hashmap` para que pueda darme la ventana de escoger la conversión.
Como se le puede pasar el valor a un método heredado en el super?. dejo el código igual si pueden decirme como quedo y si puedo mejorarlo.

```java
public class Demo {
    private static Iconverter strategy;
    private static final List<String> conversionOption = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final    List<String> money = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final Converter converter = new Converter();

    static {
        conversionOption.add("Monedas");
        conversionOption.add("Temperatura");
        money.add("A Dolar");
        money.add("A Peso Mexicano");
        money.add("A Euro");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (!converter.isEnd()) {
            String op = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "seleccione", "seleccion",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
                    conversionOption.toArray(new String[0]), conversionOption);

            try {
                switch (op) {
                    case "Monedas" -> {
                        boolean keepGoing = false;
                        do {
                            try {
                                String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el valor a convertir");
                                double receivedValue = Double.parseDouble(input);
                                String inputM = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Seleccione a que moneda " +
                                                "quiere cambiar" +
                                                " ?","seleccione",
                                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,null,money.toArray(new String[0]),money);
                                switch (inputM){
                                    case "A Dolar" ->{
                                        strategy = new ConvertToDollar(receivedValue);
                                    }
                                    case "A Peso Mexicano" ->{
                                        strategy = new ConvertToPesoMx(receivedValue);
                                    }
                                    case "A Euro" ->{
                                        strategy = new ConvertertToEuro(receivedValue);
                                    }
                                }

                            } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresar obligatoriamente un numero");
                                keepGoing = true;
                            } catch (NullPointerException nu) {
                                keepGoing = false;
                            }
                        } while (keepGoing);
                        try {
                            converter.processConver(strategy);
                        } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {

                        }
                        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea realizar otra conversion");
                        if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == option) {
                            converter.isEnd();
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saliendo del programa");
                            converter.setEnd();
                        }
                    }

                    // conversor temperatura
                    case "Temperatura" -> {
                        boolean keepGoing2 = false;
                        do {
                            try {
                                String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el valor a convertir");
                                double receivedValue2 = Double.parseDouble(input2);
                                strategy = new Temperatura(receivedValue2);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresar obligatoriamente un numero");
                                keepGoing2 = true;
                            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                keepGoing2 = false;
                            }
                        } while (keepGoing2);

                        try {
                            converter.processConver(strategy);
                        } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
                        }
                        int option2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea realizar otra conversion");
                        if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == option2) {
                            converter.isEnd();
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saliendo del programa");
                            converter.setEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                converter.setEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Converter {
    private boolean isEnd = false;
    public void processConver(Iconverter strategy){
        strategy.calculaConversion();
    }

    public boolean isEnd() {
        return isEnd;
    }

    public void setEnd() {
        isEnd = true;
    }
}

public class ConvertToDollar extends Money {

    private static final Map <String,Double> valorDolar = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        valorDolar.put("Pesos Mexicanos a Dolar", 0.059);
        valorDolar.put("Pesos Colombianos a Dolar",0.00025);
        valorDolar.put("Soles Peruanos a Dolar",0.27);
        valorDolar.put("Euros a Dolar",1.10);
        valorDolar.put("Libras Esterlinas a Dolar",1.28);
        valorDolar.put("Won sur coreano a Dolar",0.00078);
    }

    public ConvertToDollar(double value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void calculaConversion() {
        String choice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"seleccion","seleccion"
                ,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
                valorDolar.keySet().toArray(new String[0]), valorDolar);
            double choiceGetValor = valorDolar.get(choice);
            double result = value * choiceGetValor;
            result = Math.round(result * 1000.0)/ 1000.0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tienes $" + result + " " + "Dolares");
            System.out.println(choiceGetValor);
    }

public interface Iconverter {
    void   calculaConversion();
}
```

Creé esta clase moneda para poder heredar.

```java
public  class Money implements Iconverter{

    protected  double value;
    protected   Map<String,Double> valueMoney = new HashMap<>();

    public Money(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void calculaConversion() {
        String choice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"seleccion","seleccion"
                ,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
                valueMoney.keySet().toArray(new String[0]), valueMoney);
        double choiceGetValor = valueMoney.get(choice);
        double result = getValue() * choiceGetValor;
        result = Math.round(result * 1000.0)/ 1000.0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tienes $" + result + " " + choice);
        System.out.println(choiceGetValor);
    }
```

Y al querer agregarla como herencia en el `super`, no se como pasarle el valor del Hashmap.

```java
public class ConvertertToEuro extends Money {

    private static final Map<String,Double> valueMoney = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        valueMoney.put("Dolar a Euro", 0.91);
        valueMoney.put("Pesos Colombianos a Euro",0.00023);
        valueMoney.put("Soles Peruanos a Euro",0.25);
        valueMoney.put("Pesos mexicanos a Euro",0.054);
        valueMoney.put("Libras Esterlinas a Euro",1.17);
        valueMoney.put("Won sur coreano a Euro",0.00071);
    }

    public ConvertertToEuro(double value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void calculaConversion() {
        super.calculaConversion();
    }
```

Espero puedan orientame.
Nota no se por que algunas cosas del código me las tira para afuera.

Answer (score 0):

La `interfaz` **Iconverter** está de más, la interfaces se usan para adicionar un método que no puede ser heredado (java no permite herencia múltiple) y dado que todas las clases de monedas heredan la clase que tiene la interfaz.... con solo heredar alcanza.
Osea, si tengo una clase "**Vaca**" que hereda de "**Animal**" y una clase "**Tractor**" que hereda de "**Maquinaria**" y ambas necesitan un método **getPrecio()** puedo crear una interfaz que lo suministre, ya que ni "**Vaca**" puede heredar de "**Maquinaria**" ni "**Tractor**" puede heredar de "**Animal**".. sin importar quien lo maneje!.

Métodos y atributos estáticos, solo los uso cuando necesito que algo sea estático (con todas sus implicaciones).

Anotaciones **`@Override`**, cuando implementas una `interfaz`, también hay que usarla.

Herencias, cuando heredas de una clase, heredas todos sus atributos y todos sus métodos, por lo que lo siguiente no es correcto:

```
public class Money implements Iconverter {

   protected double value;
   protected Map<String, Double> valueMoney = new HashMap<>();

   public Money( double value ) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public double getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public void setValue( double value ) {
      this.value = value;
   }
      // acá falta la anotación @Override
   public void calculaConversion() {
      String choice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "seleccion", "seleccion",
              JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
              valueMoney.keySet().toArray( new String[ 0 ] ), valueMoney );
      double choiceGetValor = valueMoney.get( choice );
      double result = getValue() * choiceGetValor;
      result = Math.round( result * 1000.0 ) / 1000.0;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Tienes $" + result + " " + choice );
      System.out.println( choiceGetValor );
   }
}


public class ConvertertToEuro extends Money {

   private static final Map<String, Double> valueMoney = new HashMap<>();

  
   public ConvertertToEuro( double value ) {
      super( value );
   }

   public double getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public void setValue( double value ) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   @Override
   public void calculaConversion() {
       super.calculaConversion();
   }
}
```

Un primer acercamiento sería así:

```
public class ConvertertToEuro extends Money {

   public ConvertertToEuro( double value ) {
      super( value );
   }
}
```

Obviamos los métodos **calculaConversion**, **getValue** y **setValue** así como los atributos **valueMoney** y **value** ya que están en la clase padre.
El siguiente paso, es instanciar **valueMoney** en el constructor, para que sea usado por **calculaConversion** en la clase padre, y llamar al citado método.

```
public class ConvertertToEuro extends Money {

   public ConvertertToEuro( double value ) {
      super( value );
      valueMoney.put( "Dolar a Euro", 0.91 );
      valueMoney.put( "Pesos Colombianos a Euro", 0.00023 );
      valueMoney.put( "Soles Peruanos a Euro", 0.25 );
      valueMoney.put( "Pesos mexicanos a Euro", 0.054 );
      valueMoney.put( "Libras Esterlinas a Euro", 1.17 );
      valueMoney.put( "Won sur coreano a Euro", 0.00071 );
      super.calculaConversion();
   }
}
```

Ahora bien para quitar la interfáz tienes que modificar en la clase "Demo", las siguientes lineas del "case":

```
case "A Dolar" ->{
    new ConvertToDollar(receivedValue);
}
case "A Peso Mexicano" ->{
    new ConvertToPesoMx(receivedValue);
}
case "A Euro" ->{
    new ConvertertToEuro(receivedValue);
}
```

No es el único modo de llevarlo a cabo, hay diferentes enfoques que se pueden tomar, este es solo uno de ellos, en el que traté de respetar al máximo tu propio código.
Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, la verdad me es de mucha ayuda su comentario para poder mejorar, tengo una pregunta espero pueda responderme, trate de usar el patrón de diseño strategy y trate de seguir el patron, pero supongo que como en este proyecto no queda mucho ya que es una formula unica que se utiliza para poder convertir las divisas, y es mejor eliminar la interface y heredarlas de la clase como me comentas. me podria reocmendar alguna guia para revisar el patron de diseño ?

Comment: Fijate [acá](https://refactoring.guru/es/design-patterns/java) tal vez no sea la mejor referencia, pero me pareció bastante accesible.